# Safari swipe gesture with a non multitouch mouse

Tags: keyboard, safari, multi-touch, mouse

I love the swipe gesture but I recently switched from a Magic Mouse to a gaming mouse which is non multitouch. For the back command, Safari only offers a straight keyboard-only shortcut or the multitouch swipe gesture.

For the back command, how can I create a hybrid keyboard+mouse shortcut, like alt-left click? It has to be left click + some one-hand keyboard stroke.

I forgot to mention, I am left handed therefore I need key strokes on the left hand side of the keyboard.

Comment: Please add the current shortcut of the *back* command in Safari you want to replace? **cmd+[**? Being left-handed I would expect you to use the mouse with the left hand and a key stroke on the **right** hand side of the keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

In the example below hitting the left alt key once generates one *back* command in Safari (only). An additional mouse click is not needed.

You can use the left option/alt key as usual otherwise.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>Option_L to Option_L</name>
           <appendix>(+ When you type Option_L only without other modifiers, send Command+[ in Safari)</appendix>
           <identifier>remap.altL2altL_backward_nomod</identifier>
           <only>SAFARI</only>
           <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

If you want to use the right option/alt key instead of the left one just replace OPTION_L by OPTION_R and altL by altR everywhere in the private.xml file.

The above keycode customization is only valid for the en_US input source (and probably en_GB, en_CA etc).

If you use e.g the portuguese input source (pt_PT) then you have to choose the proper KeyCodes: to get the <kbd>[</kbd> you have to press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>. Then the line:

```
<autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R
```

has to be changed to:

```
<autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R
```

If you want to add a second custom keycode (hitting left cmd key once generates one *forward* command) use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Option_L to Option_L</name>
        <appendix>(+ When you type Option_L only without other modifiers, send Command+[ in Safari)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.altL2altL_backward_nomod</identifier>
         <only>SAFARI</only>
         <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Command_L to Command_L</name>
        <appendix>(+ When you type Command_L only without other modifiers, send Command+] in Safari)</appendix>
        <identifier>remap.cmdL2cmdR_forward_nomod</identifier>
        <only>SAFARI</only>
        <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::VK_LAZY_COMMAND_L, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

The special KeyCode VK_LAZY_COMMAND_L instead of COMMAND_L **doesn't** break the function of <kbd>cmd_left</kbd>+<kbd>Some_key</kbd>: so you can navigate forward in Safari and print the page with <kbd>cmd_left</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> without going forward once more!

Comment: I did all like you said, it does not seem to work. I did quit/restart Safari though. If I want to enable "forward" with the command key, should I create a separate xml file?

Comment: @pt109 Hmm I tested in OS X Lion 10.7.5. First it was stubborn but then it worked for me. Which keyboard layout do you use? en_us? I will retry it in Mavericks! To add other keycodes you don't have to use a second xml Simply add it below </item> and </root>.

Comment: I use el capitan 10.11.2 and a french azerty apple keyboard. I tried to activate an other, for example "change esc to caps lock", this one works!